# ClassNotFoundException for External Dependencies in Flink Session Cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink

I'm currently deploying a Flink session cluster on Kubernetes using the Flink Kubernetes operator. My Flink job, which utilizes the DataStream API for its logic, requires several external dependencies. , so I've used an init container to copy all necessary jars to a /mnt/external-jars path, which is mounted as expected.

To include these external jars in my job, I've added them to the pipeline.classpaths property in my configuration as follows:

pipeline.classpaths: file:///mnt/external-jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;file:///mnt/external-jars/flink-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar;file:///mnt/external-jars/flink-shaded-guava-30.1.1-jre-16.2.jar;file:///mnt/external-jars/kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar

Despite this setup, when submitting my job, I encounter a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This leads me to question:

Is my understanding correct that the pipeline.classpaths property is intended for loading external dependencies in this manner?
Does the Flink Kubernetes operator support the pipeline.classpaths property, or are there known limitations?
Are there any alternative approaches or workarounds within the Kubernetes operator context to ensure external dependencies are recognized and loaded correctly by the Flink job?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I add all required dependencies in the JAR file of the job.
This is also recommended by the [official documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/configuration/overview/#running-and-packaging).

If you're using Maven or Gradle you can check the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) website for the available dependencies.

Be aware that, currently, Flink 1.18.X doesn't support the JDBC connector.